# Pycharm Python Console not using virtualenv

Tags: pycharm, virtualenv

Wow, I have searched far and wide for a solution to this problem, but I cant seem to find anything.

Problem: virtualenv is activated in terminal (within pycharm) but the Python Console doesnt seem to recognize the virtualenv I created.

Steps:

1. Created virtualenv "AWS_Lambda" in terminal.  Activated it and installed some packages.
2. Went into project settings and set project interpreter to the virtualenv that exists within my project.
3. Reloaded the python console.  Still able to access packages that should not be available within the virtualenv (e.g., pandas which i didnt install).

Not sure what step I am missing, as I have activated the virtualenv in the terminal and setup the project interpreter to the virtualenv.

Here is the virtualenv activated in terminal.  Correctly showing that pandas isnt installed:
[image: terminal working]

Here is the settings for this project - correctly showing I have selected the virtualenv I created: 
[image: pycharm project interpreter settings]

However, here is the issue - I am able to access pandas in the python console: 
[image: Python Console not recognizing]